# How can I fix this cross-compilation linking error

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross-compile a project on a linux `x86_64` machine for an `arm` target, I am using `gcc-linaro-7.4.1-2019.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf`.

The error I am getting during compilation is:

```
/home/zoist/workspace/gcc-linaro-7.4.1-2019.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7.4.1/libgcc.a(_dvmd_lnx.o): In function `__aeabi_idiv0':
/home/tcwg-buildslave/workspace/tcwg-make-release_0/snapshots/gcc.git~linaro-7.4-2019.02/libgcc/config/arm/lib1funcs.S:1545: undefined reference to `raise'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My compilation flags are:

```
CFLAGS  = -mtune=cortex-a9 -march=armv7-a -Wall -Werror  \
          -nostdlib -marm -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mcpu=cortex-a9
ASFLAGS = -D__ASSEMBLY__ $(CFLAGS)
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-L$(CROSS_COMPILE_DIR)/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7.4.1/ -lgcc -Wl,-T$(LINK_SCRIPT_GEN) -nostdlib -Wl,--build-id=none
LDLIBS  = -Wl,-T$(LINK_SCRIPT_GEN) -lgcc
```

I have spent time reading similar topics online but cannot resolve my problem. Are there suggestions on how I can fix this issue?

Please let me know if you would require more information.

**Edit:**

The full command causing the error is

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -Wl,-L/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/7.4.1/ -lgcc -Wl,-T../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/../../common/basic/firmware.lnk -nostdlib -Wl,--build-id=none -o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/freertos.elf ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/../../../common/basic/basic_irq.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/../../../common/basic/basic_stdio.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/../../../common/basic/basic_string.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/../../../common/basic/libfdt/fdt.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/../../../common/basic/libfdt/fdt_ro.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/../../../common/basic/libfdt/fdt_rw.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/../../../common/basic/libfdt/fdt_strerror.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/../../../common/basic/libfdt/fdt_support.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/../../../common/basic/libfdt/fdt_sw.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/../../../common/basic/libfdt/fdt_wip.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/../../../common/basic/pic/gic.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/../../../common/basic/serial/pl01x.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/../../../common/basic/sys/vminfo.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/../../../common/basic/timer/sp804.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/../../common/basic/arch_cache_v7.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/../../common/basic/arch_irq.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/../../common/basic/arch_math.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/../basic/arch_board.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/FreeRTOS/Source/croutine.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/FreeRTOS/Source/event_groups.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/FreeRTOS/Source/list.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/MemMang/heap_4.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/FreeRTOS/Source/queue.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/FreeRTOS/Source/stream_buffer.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/FreeRTOS/Source/tasks.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/FreeRTOS/Source/timers.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/arm_entry_v7.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/glue.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/main.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/port/port.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/port/portASM.o ../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/../../common/basic/firmware.lnk -Wl,-T../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/../../common/basic/firmware.lnk -lgcc
```

Comment: Please show the actual link command that make prints.  You can elide all the object files from the command line, if there are a lot of them.

Comment: @MadScientist Added the full link command.

Comment: I don't know for sure but it looks wrong to me to put `-lgcc` twice, once in `LDFLAGS` and once in `LDLIBS`.  I don't even know why you add `-lgcc` at all: the front-end (gcc) will set up the link line properly for you and add in the right options.  I'm not sure you need the `-Wl,-L...` either, it seems like the cross-compiler should already be setting that up (but I'm not familiar with your cross-compiler environment).  And, I don't know what the linker script does but maybe it should go at the end of the link line?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will look into the suggestions.
What do you mean by linker script?

Comment: @MadScientist When I remove both `-lgcc` references and `-Wl,-L...` (the only changes I made) I get
`
../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/FreeRTOS/Source/queue.o: In function `xQueueGenericCreate':
queue.c:(.text+0x2d8): undefined reference to `__aeabi_uidiv'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:131: recipe for target '../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/freertos.elf' failed
make: *** [../../../../build/tests/arm32/vexpress-a9/freertos/freertos.elf] Error 1
`

Comment: Seems you try to build a bare metal FreeRTOS application, right ? I think you’re using the wrong cross compiler for linux targets, but you need one for bare metal (non OS) targets (arm-none-eabi GCC). Also `raise` is a linux system call ..

Comment: @HS2 Thanks for noticing this! By switching to the bare-metal cross compiler I got rid of this issue. Do you want  to write an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arm-linux-gnueabihf` cross compiler is the variant for Linux targets which requires some (Linux) OS support as the undefined reference of the `raise` Linux system call indicates.
When building a bare metal/FreeRTOS application an appropriate cross compiler has to be used. For instance the bare metal (non OS) GCC variant for 32 bit ARM CPUs is `arm-none-eabi`.
Using a bare metal cross compiler should solve the issue you’ve encountered.